# Can I use EntryProcessor in Apache Ignite with Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring-data, ignite, in-memory-data-grid

In our application, we need collocated updates performed with EntryProcessor.
But we strive to make a business logic store-agnostic for some reasons. (Assuming the other stores support the invocation of entry processor). We're considering Spring Data for the role of such store-agnostic API.
The question is, is it possible to pass somehow an entry processor to Spring Data repository methods in Apache Ignite? Something kinda:

```
T invokeForName(EntryProcessor entryProcessor, String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Business logic must be store-agnostic, but you data layer must not, if you want it to be efficient.

You can implement described invokeForName yourself, if you switch storage solution, anyway you need to implement it for a new solution, I don't think that other spring data modules has something like invokeFor*.